# Move files which contains specific text from subfolders in powershell

Tags: powershell, text, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to loop through subfolders from one folder (in a directory) with excel files which contain a specific name in the file name and move them to another folder.
I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$RootFolder = "C:\Users\files"
$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory
$TextToFind = 'text'
$DestinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\move_here'
Foreach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
{ Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Filter '*.xlsx' -File -Recurse|
where {(Get-Content $_.FullName) -match $TextToFind} |
    Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDirectory }
```

Comment: `Get-Content $_.FullName` is reading the file content, are you sure you want to do that? Also, `xml` is not Excel ?

Comment: No I just want to read the file name to get the similar text

Comment: then it should be `where { $_.Name -match $TextToFind }` if I understood correctly

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel. This is why Windows FSRM (File Server Resource Manager) exists.  File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) overview --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken, it should be enough to change the variable in the where to make the move work. Below the script with the modification:

```
$RootFolder = "C:\Users\files"
$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory
$TextToFind = 'text'
$DestinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\move_here'
Foreach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
{ Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Filter '*.xlsx' -File -Recurse|
where {$Subfolder -match $TextToFind} |
    Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDirectory }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that I don't fuly understand the question, but why not use the `-Filter` for this instead of a `Where-Object` clause afterwards?

```
$RootFolder = "C:\Users\files"
$DestinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\move_here'
$TextToFind = 'text'

$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory
foreach ($folder in $SubFolders) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter "*$TextToFind*.xlsx" -File -Recurse |
    Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDirectory -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>i have added the `-WhatIf` switch to the Move-Item cmdlet, so when testing nothing actually gets moved. Once you are satisfied that what is shown in the console is OK, remove the `-WhatIf` safety switch and run again</sup>